# Deploying jhipster-console to different remote docker machines

Tags: docker, docker-compose, jhipster, docker-machine

I've looked into deploying [jhispter-console](https://github.com/NOTtardy/jhipster-console) to different remote docker machines and wanted to clarify what's the best approach for that.

Disclaimer: my experiences with docker, docker-compose and docker-machine are quite limited and therefore I'm very thankful for [jhispter-console](https://github.com/NOTtardy/jhipster-console) and any help you can provide me.

This is what I have figured out so far.

**Don't use remote docker machines at all**

This could be an approach if you clone the jhispter-console project to the remote docker host machines and execute docker-compose locally on every remote host.

In our case, this is not possible, as we don't can/want give access to the git repository from the remote hosts.

**Issue 1: docker-compose's support for different environment is quite limited**

Again using the example of the volume `./log-monitoring/log-config/:/config-dir`. If the path for `./log-monitoring/log-config/` is not the same on all docker machines, e.g. `./log-monitoring/...` when using a local docker machine and `/home/dockeruser/...` on a remote docker machine, you would need to have two separate `docker-compose.yml`files. And with every execution of docker-compose, you would specify the yml-file to be used.

I don't really like approach of having multiple `docker-compose.yml`s just for having a few different paths.

**Issue 2: volumes in docker-compose are mapping the (remote) host machine**

No surprise here, but just to state a fact. E.g. if you define a volume for `./log-monitoring/log-config/:/config-dir` the path `./log-monitoring/log-config/` must be available on the docker host machine and not the machine you are executing docker-compose on.

This means, we have to make sure that e.g. the `logstash.conf` file must be available on the remote docker machine.

**Possible solutions**

I've looked into solving the above described issues

- Issue 1: I've found this [blog post](http://lukeswart.net/2016/03/lets-deploy-part-1/) by [Lucas Blogulus](http://lukeswart.net/) which wraps the `docker-compose` executions in a shell script. The functionality of the shell script is to take a template `compose.yml` file and substitute variable placeholders by using `envsubst`. The result is than passed to the `docker-compose` execution.
  Using this approach you can manage one `compose.yml` file and generate one for each environment on the fly.
- Issue 2: I see a way where you have another shell script to wrap the `docker-compose up -d` command. In this shell script you would copy the required files to the remote host using `scp`. Doing that the latest versions of the files would be copied to the remote host and then used when the volumes are being mounted.

**Thank you for your feedback / help!**

- What's your opinion on the best way to use [jhispter-console](https://github.com/NOTtardy/jhipster-console) on multiple remote docker machines?
- I'm I wrong with all the stuff mentioned above?
- Any other thoughts?

Comment: Other thought: Look into Kubernetes (kubernetes.io)

Comment: why don't you use our pre-built image at https://hub.docker.com/r/jhipster/jhipster-console/ ?

Comment: Because we have to add things like environment specific SSL certificates, etc.

Comment: I think it's quite common to mount stuff from the host environment which cannot be built into the image itself